# Specifying minimum cluster size with OpenLayers 3 Clustering?

Tags: openlayers, clustering

With OpenLayers 3, how can I specify a minimum cluster size so that clusters with 5 map markers or less will not get clustered, but will instead display the individual map markers?

Is there a way to do this within the cluster layer's ol.layer.Vector object?

```
let clusterLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ 
source: source, 
style: function(feature, resolution) { } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this functionality is supported at the moment. You could create a new issue for it https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues